# Parse multiple XML Tags in Go

Tags: xml, go

I'm trying to parse an xml file for sslscan which has the following output (shortened).
I want to parse it with Go.

```
<document title="SSLScan Results">
 <ssltest host="x.x.x.x" port="443">
   <cipher status="accepted" sslversion="TLSv1.0" bits="256" cipher="DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA" dhebits="2048" />
             .
             .
   <cipher status="accepted" sslversion="TLSv1.2" bits="112" cipher="DES-CBC3-SHA" />               .

  <certificate>
   <not-valid-before>Jun  6 00:00:00 2014 GMT</not-valid-before>
   <not-valid-after>Jul  4 23:59:59 2017 GMT</not-valid-after>
  </certificate>
 </ssltest>
</document>
```

Code:

```
type XMLStrap struct {
  Status     string `xml:"status,attr"`
  SSLversion string `xml:"sslversion,attr"`
  Bits       string `xml:"bits,attr"`
  Cipher     string `xml:"cipher,attr"`
}

type XMLStraps struct {
  XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"document"`
  Straps  []XMLStrap `xml:"ssltest>cipher"`
}

func ReadStraps(reader io.Reader) ([]XMLStrap, error) {
  var xmlStraps XMLStraps
  if err := xml.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&xmlStraps); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return xmlStraps.Straps, nil
}


func main() {
  strapsFilePath, err := filepath.Abs("straps.xml")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  file, err := os.Open(strapsFilePath)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  defer file.Close()

  xmlStraps, err := ReadStraps(file)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  for i := 0; i < len(xmlStraps); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%s %s %s %s\n", xmlStraps[i].Status,      xmlStraps[i].SSLversion, xmlStraps[i].Bits, xmlStraps[i].Cipher)
  }
}
```

Everything works fine but I have no idea how to parse the date in `<certificate><not-valid-before>` without creating a new reader?

I tried to change the first two structs to

```
type XMLStrap struct {
  Status     string `xml:"cipher>status,attr"`
  SSLversion string `xml:"cipher>sslversion,attr"`
  Bits       string `xml:"cipher>bits,attr"`
  Cipher     string `xml:"cipher>cipher,attr"`
  Cert       string `xml:"certificate>not-valid-after,chardata"`
}

type XMLStraps struct {
  XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"document"`
  Straps  []XMLStrap `xml:"ssltest"`
}
```

but this doesn't work.

`xml: cipher>status chain not valid with attr flag
exit status 1`

Apparently in older versions of Go it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to allocate the parameter of a new object to the object which was returned. I tried this before but I did a mistake

```
type XMLStrap struct {
  Status     string `xml:"status,attr"`
  SSLversion string `xml:"sslversion,attr"`
  Bits       string `xml:"bits,attr"`
  Cipher     string `xml:"cipher,attr"`
  Valid      string ""
}

type Certs struct {
  Cert string `xml:"not-valid-after"`
}

type XMLStraps struct {
  XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"document"`
  Straps     []XMLStrap `xml:"ssltest>cipher"`
  Validation Certs      `xml:"ssltest>certificate"`
}

func ReadStraps(reader io.Reader) ([]XMLStrap, error) {
  var xmlStraps XMLStraps
  if err := xml.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&xmlStraps); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  xmlStraps.Straps[0].Valid = xmlStraps.Validation.Cert
  return xmlStraps.Straps, nil
}
```